# How to hide empty accordion content?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am writing a page using ASP.NET C# environment. I have 7 categories which are shown in a jQuery UI Accordion widget. In other words I have 7 tabs.

Each accordion content comes from DB.

Sometimes some categories are empty. So I want to hide the empty categories.

My head content has those codes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true, 
            heightStyle: "content", 
            active: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the body has those:

```
<div id="accordion">
            <h3>
                <span id="a" runat="server"></span>
            </h3>
            <div>
                <span id="atifa" runat="server"></span>
            </div>
            <h3>
                <span id="b" runat="server"></span>
            </h3>
            <div>
                <span id="atifb" runat="server"></span>
            </div>
            <h3>
                <span id="c" runat="server"></span>
            </h3>
            <div>
                <span id="atifc" runat="server"></span>
            </div>
            <h3>
                <span id="d" runat="server"></span>
            </h3>
            <div>
                <span id="atifd" runat="server"></span>
            </div>
            <h3>
                <span id="e" runat="server"></span>
            </h3>
            <div>
                <span id="atife" runat="server"></span>
            </div>
            <h3>
                <span id="f" runat="server"></span>
            </h3>
            <div>
                <span id="atiff" runat="server"></span>
            </div>
            <h3>
                <span id="g" runat="server"></span>
            </h3>
            <div>
                <span id="atifg" runat="server"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In according to record's properties, some categories come empty from the DB.
I do not want the empty categories to be shown.
Regards.

Comment: Should'nt you really be showing us the serverside code then ?

Comment: Can you post some code which you get with empty categories and the same code after hiding empty categories (how you want to it should look)?

Comment: @MateuszRogulski I populate the spans' inside in the divs. if `dt.Rows.Count > 0` the content is built, else passes to next category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $span = $("#accordion_atiflar > div > span:empty");
$span.parent('div').hide();
$span.parent('div').prev('h3').hide();
```

Comment: Thank for your attention. This code clears the content only. I also want to hide the clickable tab for the category which is empty.

Comment: we can develop this proposal, if  `$("#accordion > div > span:empty")` hide its parent and `<h3>` tag before it. But I do not know jQuery so much.

Comment: `if($("#accordion > div > span").html() === "") {

}`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are workin in asp.net, you can do not render empty Accordion tabs. You will do transfer less data to client, and simple check is really fast so it won't be a performance issue

Comment: What I am looking for is to fix this issue using jquery?

Comment: When I add `runat="server"` parameter to `<div id="accordion">`, accordion booms. I have tried to make it from the codebehind. I was unable.